# in fullcalendar when clicking on an event with an associated url

Tags: jquery

In full calendar when clicking on an event with an associated URL, how you do you change from the default open in active window to opening the URL in a new window or tab?

I have found the event function on Arshaws docs but cannot find the relevent function in any of the scripts. Do I need to add the click-event function, and if so where?

Sorry, im still having problems with this, this is the script im using to control the calendar, im not sure how to add the event parameters via json format to get the click function to open the event in a new window. I have indicated the event function im having a problem with

```
     <script type='text/javascript'>
        $(document).ready(function() {

        var date = new Date();
        var d = date.getDate();
        var m = date.getMonth();
        var y = date.getFullYear(); 
        var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            editable: true,
            weekMode: 'liquid',
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },

            events: "fullcalendar/fullcalendar/events.php",

            // Convert the allDay from string to boolean
   eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
    if (event.allDay === 'true') {
     event.allDay = true;
    } else {
     event.allDay = false;
    }
   },

            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
            select: function(start, end, allDay) {
                var title = prompt('Event Title:');
                var url = prompt('Type Event url, if exits:');
                if (title) {

    var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(end, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
   $.ajax({
   url: 'fullcalendar/fullcalendar/add_events.php',
   data: 'title='+ title+'&start='+ start +'&end='+ end +'&url='+ url ,
   type: "POST",
   success: function(json) {
   alert('Added Successfully');
   }
   })

                    calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                        {
                            title: title,
                            start: start,
                            end: end,
                            allDay: allDay
                        },
                        true // make the event "stick"
                    );
                }
                calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
            },
            editable: true,


               eventDrop: function(event, delta) {
   var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
   var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
   $.ajax({
   url: 'fullcalendar/fullcalendar/update_events.php',
   data: 'title='+ event.title+'&start='+ start +'&end='+ end +'&id='+ event.id ,
   type: "POST",
   success: function(json) {
    alert("Updated Successfully");
   }
   });
   },
      eventResize: function(event) {
   var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
   var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
   $.ajax({
    url: 'fullcalendar/fullcalendar/update_events.php',
    data: 'title='+ event.title+'&start='+ start +'&end='+ end +'&id='+ event.id ,
    type: "POST",
    success: function(json) {
     alert("Updated Successfully");
    }
    });
    },
        eventClick: function(event) {
var decision = confirm("Do you really want to delete this Event?"); 
if (decision==true) {
$.ajax({
url: 'fullcalendar/fullcalendar/delete_events.php',
data:'&id=' + event.id,
type: "POST",
success: function(json) {
    alert("Removed Succesfully");
}
});
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', event.id);

****************************************************************************
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
events: [
    {
        title: 'My Event',
        start: '2010-01-01',
        url: 'http://stackoverflow.com/'
    }
    // other events here
],
eventClick: function(event) {
    if (event.url) {
        window.open(event.url, "_blank");
        return false;
    }
*****************************************************************************
}
});

} else {
}
}

  });

 });


</script>
```

Comment: that is the code i found on Arshaws docs, the trouble is I dont seem to be able to find this fuction in any of the scripts, could you tell me where this function resides please. Or is it simply a case off adding it to the script used on the page that calls the calender?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use the eventClick callback in fullcalendar

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
events: [
    {
        title: 'My Event',
        start: '2010-01-01',
        url: 'http://stackoverflow.com/'
    }
    // other events here
],
eventClick: function(event) {
    if (event.url) {
        window.open(event.url, "_blank");
        return false;
    }
}
});
```

Comment: that is the code i found on Arshaws docs, the trouble is I dont seem to be able to find this function in any of the scripts, could you tell me where this function resides please. Or is it simply a case of adding it to the script used on the page that calls the calender? also what do i need to put into the title, start, url elements in this script to get the data provided for the event created from the calling of data from the database

Comment: You just have to add the eventClick function to the script that you use to call the calendar. If you are getting all your events from your database then you just have to pass it in a json format to the _events_ parameter.

Comment: Please mark this as an answer if it worked for you so that others can know that its solved.

Comment: soory, still having problems im not sure how to pass the events through json to the events parameter, this the script im using for controling the calendar

Comment: Seems to me that your original code will work fine. just remove the additions that you have made and put the if condition that i mentioned in the eventClick callback. Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MbQq2/1/)

Answer (score 10):

If using V4 of FullCalendar, try this instead:

```
  eventClick: function(event) {
    if (event.event.url) {
      event.jsEvent.preventDefault()
      window.open(event.event.url, "_blank");
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for this!

If you want to distinguish between internal linking (same window) and external linking (new window), you could solve it as follows:

```
...

eventClick: function(event) { 
    // If extern url/domain 
    if (event.url.indexOf(document.location.hostname) === -1) {
       // Open url in new window
       window.open(event.url, "_blank");
       // Deactivate original link
       return false;
    }
},
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        fullCalendar({
            viewRender: function(view, element) {
                if (view.name != 'month') {
                    $(element).find('.fc-scroller').perfectScrollbar();
                }
            },
            header: {
                left: 'title',
                center: 'month',
                right: 'prev,next,today'
            },
            defaultDate: today,
            disableDragging: true,
            editable: false,
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
            views: {
                month: { // name of view
                    titleFormat: 'MMMM YYYY'
                },
                week: {
                    titleFormat: " MMMM D YYYY"
                },
                day: {
                    titleFormat: 'D MMM, YYYY'
                }
            },
            select: function(start, end) {
                swal({
                    title: 'Create an Event',
                    html: '<div class="form-group">' +
                    '<input class="form-control" placeholder="Event Title" id="input-field">' +
                    '</div>',
                    showCancelButton: true,
                    confirmButtonClass: 'btn btn-success',
                    cancelButtonClass: 'btn btn-danger',
                    buttonsStyling: false
                }).then(function(result) {
                    var eventData;
                    event_title = $('#input-field').val();
                    if (event_title) {
                        eventData = {
                            title: event_title,
                            start: start,
                            end: end
                        };
                        $calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true); // stick? = true
                    }
                    $calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
                }).catch(swal.noop);
            },
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            events: {
                url: base_url+'p-teacher/calendar.php',
                failure: function() {
                    document.getElementById('script-warning').style.display = 'block'
                }
            },
            eventClick: function(event) {
                if (event.url) {
                    window.open(event.url, "_blank");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
```

This works for me.